# How to make a Youtube player popout and play a video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, youtube

I have a YouTube player which plays a video using the YouTube API, The problem is that it redirects to another page and then starts playing the video.

How do i make the player pop-out on the same page at the click of an image and then start playing the video?

```
<a href="play/"><img src="image" alt="button-img" /></a>

//play is the route where YouTube player component is present.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a click event and insert the iframe of the youtube video in the place you want. Here you have an example...

**HTML**:

```
<a href="#" id="showvideo">Show Video</a>
<div id="test"></div>
```

**JQUERY**:

```
$('a#showvideo').click(function(e) {    
    e.preventDefault();        
    $('div#test').html('<iframe id="video" width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/aS3DPglji0o?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
});
```

Comment: Hey, i ran this. But the video is not popping out nor playing.

Comment: Didn't install `@types/jquery` so it didn't work that time. Thanks.